# Photoshop pattern program

Tags: photoshop

Let's say I don't have photoshop, but I want to make pattern files  (.pat) out of an image. Are there any kind of API's out there to do that.? I have searched the web but without luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@chrene Hrm.... Interesting. I have worked on stuff like that before if I'm understanding you correctly check out: [www.generatorx.no](http://www.generatorx.no)/ or [www.artofillusion.org](http://www.artofillusion.org)/ or this kind of stuff is software created by artists for artists kind of thing. I'm not sure what you mean by algorithm but if you mean something like this: www.processing.org/ you will for sure be able to do it through that platform. Best of luck and I hope I helped. And I have worked pretty extensively with processing so let me know if you have any other questions. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

Paint Shop Pro Photo X2, CorelDRAW Graphics Suite, ACD Systems Canvas 11 are all programs that you can use and can view .pat files. As far as creating .pat files I know for sure that Corel has the ability to make them.

Comment: Allright, however I wan't to make them through an algorithm and some with some kind of API, so I can make my own program to do it for me.